# php creating average of scores to display

Tags: php, average, display

A newbie to php, attempting to solve a quick problem before I delve more deeply into the language, I have the following code but want it to display only the **AVERAGE** of all the scores generated.

```
<p>Average Score</p>
                <?php


                $a = new NewQuizScore;
                $scores = $a->getScores($_SESSION['username']);

                foreach ($scores as $score) {
                    echo ("<tr>");
                    echo ("<td>".$score[0]. "</td> ");
                    echo ("<td>".$score[1]. "</td> ");
                    echo ("</tr>");
                }



                ?>
```

**Currently it displays the scores themselves as shown below.**

```
1-Python Basics 100 1-Python Output 100 2-Python Output 90 3-Variables and User Input 100
```

Would someone be able to post the most efficient way to create a variable to store the average and display it on the screen. In the example above it would produce the average of the scores 100, 100, 90 and 100

I tried to play around with the code to remove the "" but it resulted in the page not loading at all.

**UPDATE:**
Using the answer below I used the below, but the average is showing as: 101.25 rather than 97.5

```
<p>Average Score</p>
                <?php
                $avg = 0;
                foreach ($scores as $score) {
                $avg += array_sum($score);
                }
                $avg /= count($scores);
                echo "<tr> <td>$avg</td></tr>"



                ?>
                <p></br></br></br></br></p>
```

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? It sounds like simple mathematics. But you should probably do this in sql if the data comes from a database.

Comment: It's more to do with the PHP syntax combined with the displaying it on a browser, which I don't know! for instance, in python it would simply be: average=score1+score2+score3+score4 print(average)

Comment: Move the echos under the foreach and use the foreach as a means to calculate the average.

Answer (score 0):

for display average you try this

```
$total=0;
foreach ($scores as $score) {
         $total=$total+$score;
}
$average= ($total/sizeof($scores));
echo $average;
```

also you can try this

```
$array = array(1, 7, 9, 3, 20, 12, 2, 9);

$average = array_sum($array) / count($array);

echo $average;
```

you can check [output](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aed28040f9ac88730e231ebb85dcd8b1bef457fd)

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? I will try this in a minute, thank you ...

Comment: i hate these peoples that click on down-vote without comments

Comment: I tried <p>Average Score</p>
                <?php
                $total=0;
                foreach ($scores as $score) {
                         $total=$total+$score;
                }
                $average= ($total/sizeof($scores));
                echo $average;

                





                ?> but it doesn't load the page.  Are you able to paste in the exact suggested solution with my existing code (e.g,. Average Score etc tags all included)

Comment: `NewQuizScore`  is this class? also show complete code.. i think error is something else

Comment: You edit the question, fix the error (*100, really?) and you don't know what the downvote was for. Right.

Comment: @jeroen yes.. this is my mistake.. but my point is you should comment for down-vote .. you know in stackoverflow a lot of debate about down-vote without comments. also you have high reputation and you know better

Comment: I disagree, I don't have to do anything and some things are simply so bad that I can't be bothered to write a comment. And it worked, didn't it ;-)

Comment: Hi Bilal - the below answer works, but it's coming up with the wrong average. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You could use array_sum if your score array were one-dimensional e.g. array(30,"question1"):

```
$average = array_sum($scores)/(count($scores)/2);
```

Since it's not, you have to do it within a loop

```
$avg = 0;
foreach ($scores as $score) {
$avg += array_sum($score);
}
$avg /= count($scores);
```

Comment: Thanks - this doesn't display anything. Could you please post with my existing code with tags, and for the display of the average variable as well please? I tried echo $average; ...will that work?

Comment: Simply add echo "<tr> <td>$avg</td></tr>" after the last line of my code. This will display the average score only.

Comment: why not simply echo $average as opposed to echo "<tr> <td>$avg</td></tr>"

Comment: The average is displaying as: 101.25

Comment: It should be 97.5   ...any thoughts?

Comment: I would be able to accept your answer if you answered this!

Comment: Would have been great if we had a var_dump($scores) so we could see the actual array. But $avg += intval($score[1]) instead of array_sum should do it. 

I just copied your format with tr/td, you can actually just write echo $avg if you don't need the tr/td stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like using [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) so here's an example using that:

```
 <p>Average Score</p>
 <?php
    $a = new NewQuizScore;
    $scores = $a->getScores($_SESSION['username']);
    $average = array_reduce($scores, function ($carry, $value) use ($scores) {
        return $carry + $value/count($scores);
   }, 0.0);

    echo ("<tr>");
    echo ("<td>".$average. "</td> ");    
    echo ("</tr>");



    ?>
```

This will go through the array and aggregate the value `$value/count($scores)` for each value in the array.